# Xcode7 failed to check modified files for svn

Tags: svn, xcode7

Yesterday I checked out certain version of remote respository and made some change. And now I have two 'branches' in local respository, one is master, another is certain version.

However, when I try to check commit history of svn in Xcode today, I find it fails to show modified files and an alert, saying `The source control operation failed because no working copy could be found. Make sure the file is in a valid working copy and try again.`

It's really annoying to unable to check any detail modified code.

Is it an Xcode bug? or what should I do with my SVN?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question. First, I think this is maybe [libgit2.dylb bug](http://wenda.baba.io/questions/3240553/os-x-server-3-2-1-bot-cant-get-source-from-repository.html). Build new one bug can't fix it.

Comment: @fengxing With no luck, I'm still facing this problem till now. I've tested with a project using git, and it worked perfectly! Sigh. o(╯□╰)o

Comment: Same Question. Xcode 7.0~7.1.1