# cant see history Xcode 7 and VisualSVN Server

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, visualsvn-server

[image: Xcode 7 and VisualSVN Server fails to load history]

[image: no working copy found]

Xcode 7 and VisualSVN Server fails to load history. it was working fine on older version but after updating xcode 7 this issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

The error states that it is not possible to view the file's history because it is not in a working copy. You should double-check that the file is located in the working copy and the working copy is valid. I'd suggest running `svn checkout` to get a new working copy with your project and checking whether you can reproduce this.

BTW, quick search of the error message makes me think that it could be a new bug in Xcode IDE. There is a number of similar questions on StackOverflow

- [Xcode7 failed to check modified files for svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707891/xcode7-failed-to-check-modified-files-for-svn)
- [Xcode source control view history modified files fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774422/xcode-source-control-view-history-modified-files-fail)

and a bug report on Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23578

Comment: i done svn checkout and it doesnt work. i have reported this issue to apple bug. issue is still open in bug inspector.